# Running same command through TexStudio and CLI yield different `stdout`

Tags: errors, compiling, texstudio

I am running the command `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode "document".tex` in **TexStudio** and **CLI**. In TexStudio the setting is active for showing all the `stdout` unless it is redirected to `/dev/null`.

**EDIT**:

[Command prompt log](https://pastebin.com/M4XrXfx2)

[TexStudio Log](https://pastebin.com/yLqPW3Yj)

There is an error in my document which causes the Latex engine to run indefinitely without stopping. However, in the `stdout` of the command prompt in Windows I see the error causing this behavior **which greatly facilitates the troubleshooting procedure.** Why is this message not displayed in TexStudio? As I mentioned before I ran exactly the same command in both scenarios. The [MWE](https://pastebin.com/AHn7d1mH) and the last lines of the corresponding `stdout` from **Texstudio** is:

```
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/gettitlestring.sty))
(./document.out) (./document.out)

No file document.bbl.
(./_minted-document/default-pyg-prefix.pygstyle)
ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/uesint.fd)
```

Whereas the last lines of `stdout` from the **DOS command prompt** on Windows is:

```
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msa.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/microtype/mt-msb.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/esint/uesint.fd)
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \l__xparse_processor_int
l.36            \tikzmath{\ang = 45;}
                            ;
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \l__xparse_processor_int
l.36            \tikzmath{\ang = 45;}
                            ;

!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! siunitx error: "invalid-number"
!
! Invalid numerical input '='.
!
! See the siunitx documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................

l.36            \tikzmath{\ang = 45;}
                            ;
```

The actual error message is only displayed in the second case and it is much more explanatory. As can be seen the `TexStudio` version seems to be a truncated version of the `stdout` from the command prompt. Why is this the case and how can I have both of them the same?

Comment: We'll need to see full logs: almost certainly you are picking up different files so have some difference in paths.

Comment: @JosephWright You mean that the versions of the `pdftex` engine is different?

Comment: @JosephWright I provided the corresponding `log files`.